# Is the code properly documented/commented and does the code handle errors properly?

Tags: c#

Is the code properly documented/commented?
does the code handle errors properly? any suggestions to improve the code
Help outline the object-oriented principles shown in the code.

````
using System;

public class testScore
{
    
    public static void Main()
    {
    
        string str1;
        double dbl1;

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Acme Student Test Score comenter");

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
        str1 = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the test score");
        dbl1 = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", str1);
        Console.WriteLine("You scored {0}", dbl1);

        if(dbl1 < 40)
        {
            if (dbl1 > 0)
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("This a FAIL score");
            }
        }
        if ((dbl1 >= 40) && (dbl1 <= 100))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is a PASS score");

            if (dbl1 >= 75)
                Console.WriteLine("You did very well!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Oh dear - you have put in a wrong test score");
        }
    } 
}
```
````

Comment: `Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine())` will throw an exception on invalid input. Use [Double.TryParse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_Double_TryParse_System_String_System_Double__) instead. As of comments: you don't have a single one.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: You ask about `documented/commented`, I find no *documentation* or *code comments* in the code presented. I don't dare to try and imagine how program source code could conceivably *show object-oriented principles*.

Comment: Because C# is a procedural programming language (mostly) that's why your code (alone without comments) should be able to use to answer to the **What** and **How** questions. On the other hand your code will not capture the **why**s and **why not**s. So, your comments should capture your decisions: why did you choose path A over path B; why did you exclude path C and path D ...

Comment: @alex if [zareb](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/247166/zareb) is your registered account and you would like them to be merged, then you can click the [contact link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/contact) in the lower left corner of the page and request your accounts to be merged.

Answer (score 3):

**Variables**

You've defined `str1` and `dbl1` as variable names, but the names themselves aren't descriptive of their use. Better names for them would be:

```
string name;
double score;
```

Along with this, there's no reason why you can't instantiate the variable at the same time as the declaration:

```
string name = Console.ReadLine();
```

**Error Handling**

As it currently stands, there's one place where a runtime exception can occur, which is `Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine())`. If a user decides to enter `ten` as the score input, an error will occur. We can use `Double.TryParse` instead, and we can add retry logic if an invalid input was entered. We can also add logic to retry if an invalid number was entered (e.g. 200). Something like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the test score");
bool successfulInput = false;
do
{
    successfulInput = Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out score);

    if (!successfulInput)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Score must be a number");    
    }
    else if (score < 0 || score > 100)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oh dear - you have put in a wrong test score");
        successfulInput = false;
    }
} while (!successfulInput);
```

**Methods**

Split up behaviour into Methods for better cohesion and readability. We can extract the logic to determine the grade into a method like:

```
static void DisplayGrade(string name, double score)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", name);
    Console.WriteLine("You scored {0}", score);

    if ((score >= 40) && (score <= 100))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a PASS score");

        if (score >= 75)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You did very well!");
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("This a FAIL score");
    }
}
```

We can do this for all the different behaviours we want to capture (which I will show at the end).

**Magic Numbers**

There are numbers such as 40, 100, and 75 which is not very descriptive of their intent alone. These numbers can be replaced with by `const` variables:

```
const int PASS_MARK = 40;
const int TOP_MARK = 100;
const int GOOD_MARK = 75;
```

This would look something like:

```
static void DisplayGrade(string name, double score)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", name);
    Console.WriteLine("You scored {0}", score);

    if ((score >= PASS_MARK) && (score <= TOP_MARK))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a PASS score");

        if (score >= GOOD_MARK)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You did very well!");
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("This a FAIL score");
    }
}
```

**Final Results**

If we apply these techniques, we'd get something along the lines of:

```
using System;

public class testScore
{
    const int PASS_MARK = 40;
    const int TOP_MARK = 100;
    const int GOOD_MARK = 75;
    const int MIN_MARK = 0;
        
    public static void Main()
    {
        DisplayWelcomeMessage();

        string name = GetNameInput();
        double score = GetScoreInput();

        DisplayGrade(name, score);
    } 
    
    static void DisplayWelcomeMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Acme Student Test Score comenter");
    }
    
    static string GetNameInput()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }
    
    static double GetScoreInput()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the test score");
        
        double score;
        bool successfulInput = false;
        do
        {
            successfulInput = Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out score);
            if (!successfulInput)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Score must be a number");    
            }
            else if (score < MIN_MARK || score > TOP_MARK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Oh dear - you have put in a wrong test score");
                successfulInput = false;
            }
        } while (!successfulInput); 
        
        return score;
    }
    
    static void DisplayGrade(string name, double score)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", name);
        Console.WriteLine("You scored {0}", score);

        if ((score >= PASS_MARK) && (score <= TOP_MARK))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is a PASS score");

            if (score >= GOOD_MARK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You did very well!");
            }
        }
        else
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("This a FAIL score");
        }
    }
}
```

**A Note on comments**

While your original question did ask if the code was properly commented (which there were no comments), I'm of the belief that unless it's a public API, then comments don't have real value if your code is easy to read. The steps taken here are to ensure that the code is highly readable.

Comment: agree with last point, comments are completely redundent except for maybe cases with magic numbers (like hex memory addresses) or more complex alghorytms (like reading backwards from a hex file to ensure little-endianess)